# Error in sending large file with retrofit multipart POST request

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

i'm using retrofit2 library for post data to server, I need to upload a file or photo with POST request and get it's response. So i have two ways:

1. Encoding the file to base64 and sending it as a text in post body.
2. Using Multi part request and sending the file directly .

And i tried them, but in both ways, i have same problem:
when I send small files (for example under 500 bytes),I get successful result.
But the problem occurs when i send a large file. I get nothing until the timeout finishes, in AVD I get successful response (Also in Postman), but in real devices (HTC with android 5.1 & Samsung S6 with Android 7.0) the below error occurs:

`java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{myIp:port, proxy=DIRECT@ hostAddress=/myIp:port cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1`

Call Method:

```
@Multipart
@POST("uploaddata")
Call<ResponseBody> uploaddate(@Part("file") RequestBody filePart, @Part("token") RequestBody token,
                              @Part("type") RequestBody type, @Part("name")RequestBody name);
```

Main method:

```
public void uploadImage(String type, File file, String name, String token, final DataInterface listener) {

    RequestBody filePart = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
    RequestBody tokenPart = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), token);
    RequestBody namePart = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), name);
    RequestBody typePart = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), type);

    Call<ResponseBody> uploadData = apiInterface.uploaddate(filePart, tokenPart, typePart, namePart);
    uploadData.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                listener.onResponseListener(response.body());

            } else {

                Log.e(TAG, "uploadData -----> response.isSuccessful == false");

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "uploadData onFailure -----> " + t);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the log output of your error
Did it return anything like a large binary data ??

Try this:

```
@Multipart
@POST("uploaddata")
Call<ResponseBody> uploaddate(@Part MultiPart.Body filePart, 
@Part("token") RequestBody token,
                          @Part("type") RequestBody type, 
@Part("name")RequestBody name);
```

Main method:

```
public void uploadImage(String type, File file, String name, String token, 
final DataInterface listener) {

RequestBody filePart = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
MultiPartBody.Part body = MultiPartBody.Part.createFormData("filePart",file.getName(),filePart);
RequestBody tokenPart = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), token);
RequestBody namePart = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), name);
RequestBody typePart = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), type);

Call<ResponseBody> uploadData = apiInterface.uploaddate(body, tokenPart, typePart, namePart);
uploadData.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {

            listener.onResponseListener(response.body());

        } else {

            Log.e(TAG, "uploadData -----> response.isSuccessful == false");

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e(TAG, "uploadData onFailure -----> " + t);
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Logcat error: `java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{myIp:port, proxy=DIRECT@ hostAddress=/myIp:port cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1`

Comment: did it return anything like this:
D/OkHttp: ������JFIF����������������C��

Comment: @DilipKrishna It do return this in my case so what can be the issue?